# Merging MySQL columns by ID then putting it to another table

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a table that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05NhI.png) -- which is named orders. I want to merge all rows with the same customerID at the same time appending the 'productName' column.

So basically what I want to happen is:

```
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Customer ID | Name    |Order                 |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| 9           |Christian|wazung                |
| 9           |Christian|Custom Watercooled PC |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

to this:

```
+-----------------------+------------------------------+
| Customer ID | Name    |Order                         |
+-----------------------+------------------------------+
| 9           |Christian|wazung, Custom Watercooled PC |
+-----------------------+------------------------------+
```

Also take note that I have an 'orderID' column which is my primary key, auto increment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to accomplish your task. The default delimiter is `,`. You can read the documentation of it and tweak the results accordingly.

```
SELECT CustomerID, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Order) AS Order
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY CustomerID, Name
```